# Template expression evaluation frequency

Tags: angular, performance, angular-changedetection

Suppose we have these in an Angular 2 template:

```
<div>{{ firstName + ' ' + lasstName }}</div>
...
<div>{{ getFullName(person) }}</div>
...
<img [src]="baseUrl + '/' + 'area' + '/' + 'image'">
...
<img [src]="getFullAvatarUrl(person)">
```

I'm wondering whether those expressions would be evaluated each change detection cycle in a `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default` component?

Or Angular does know which properties every expression depends on and re-eveluates them only when those properties change?

What about using methods in the expressions - is Angular able to figure out whether a method is pure so it could figure out which properties should lead to the expression re-evaluation?

Comment: Angular always recalculates expressions and then compares with previous values. You can simply check it by putting breakpoint in ngfactory

Comment: @yurzui, so this basically means that a pure pipe is ALWAYS more efficient than ANY template expression? Even though evaluating a simple expression like `firstName + ' ' + lasstName` is not a real performance bottleneck. Is this correct?

Comment: Pure pipe will be evaluated only if any of its inputs has changed. Yes, pure pipe is more efficient in heavy computing.

Comment: I tested it here https://ng-run.com/edit/kciSIE99Bgr3g5QVzKkA Here's simple case http://take.ms/s6PiN

Comment: @yurzui, awesome, thank you for this! It's interesting that just making `TestPipe` pure also prevents `test()` from getting called so many times!